# How to find the gradient for a given discrete 3D mesh?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

I have a 3D mesh that is looking like this:
[image]

ie I have a set of triangles in a 3D space, and they are all linked by their edge.
I have to compute the gradient associated with this field, at each edge of the mesh. For a continuous function it would be  the derivative along the X and Y axis, but in this case I can't do this. 
How can I compute this? I'm not even sure how I can define the (approximate) gradient in this situation.

thanks

Comment: Is there a function $f(\mathbf{x}), x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, whose gradient $\nabla f$ should be evaluated at all vertices/edges of your mesh? Or is f only defined on the mesh? For me "gradient associated with this field" is unclear in your question. Do you have any further information on the problem?

Comment: @ArminB : the mesh is an approximation of z = sin(x+y) . I have to compare the gradient of this mesh to the gradient of the exact function. So for my question I need to compute the gradient just based on this approximate mesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express your problem differently:

If you keep in mind that *"the gradient of a function at a point is perpendicular to the level set of the function at that point"* - ie that for a function defining a surface, the gradient will be normal to this surface ([Q: Why is the gradient normal?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1977/why-is-the-gradient-normal)) - then all you want to do with your mesh is to **compute its vertices' unit normals**.

Using this wording, you should find plenty of methods to do so. For instance, here is a simple algorithm described by Perlin [here](http://mrl.nyu.edu/%7Eperlin/courses/fall2002/meshnormals.html):

> 1. Initialize all the vertex normals to the null vector. In the next step, you're going to gradually accumulate values into these vectors.
> 2. Loop through all the faces of your mesh. For each face, consider all pairs of successive edges around the face. For example, if your
>    face has vertices A,B,C,D, in that order, then you would consider the
>    four pairs of successive edges:
>
>    - A→B and B→C
>    - B→C and C→D
>    - C→D and D→A
>    - D→A and A→B
>
>    For each pair of successive edges $e_1$ and $e_2$, take the cross product $e_1 × e_2$. Add the resulting vector to the normal of every
>    vertex that adjoins the face (for example, in this case you would add
>    to the normals of vertices A,B,C,D).
> 3. Loop through all the vertices, and normalize the length of the normal vector of each one.